# What is $\int f$ if $f$ is not Riemann integrable in the reverse direction of this theorem

Tags: real-analysis

Consider following theorem:

[image]

I wanted to prove the $\Longleftarrow$ direction when I run into trouble. I do not understand the expression $|R(f,P)-A|$. Here $R(f,P)$ is a Riemann sum with respect to a tagged partition $P$. But at this point we do not know that $f$ is Riemann integrable, it is what we want to show. But $A=\int_a^b f$ is the Riemann integral of $f$. (It is defined to be the sup of the upper sums (or inf of the lower sums, they are equal if $f$ is Riemann integrable)).

How to interpret $A=\int_a^b f$ if $f$ is not know to be Riemann integrable?

Comment: You don't. Note that for the $\Leftarrow$ direction, you only use the Riemann sums, and those exist whether the function is Riemann integrable or not. If the limit of the Riemann sums exists, then the function is Riemann integrable, and its integral is the limit of the Riemann sums.

Comment: When the limit of the Riemann sum exists, we say that $f$ is Riemann integrable, if the limit of the Riemann sum doesn't exists, then we claim that  $f$ is not Remann integrable. $\int_a^b$ is just a symbol, when the Riemann sum converges under any parition and axiom, then we define the Rimann integral of $f$ on interval $[a, b]$to be $\int_a^b f$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The author means "...iff there exists a number $A$ with the following property: ...". If such number exists, we denote $A=\displaystyle\int_a^b f$.